# Apache camel Error - cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'headerName' is not allowed to appear in element 'setHeader'."

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

Greetings friend when using the component set header in apache camel it throws me the following error when I do the deployment in EAP

/META-INF/jboss-camel-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 48; columnNumber: 79; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'headerName' is not allowed to appear in element 'setHeader'.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 48; columnNumber: 79; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'headerName' is not allowed to appear in element 'setHeader'. "}}

Then I remove the headerName attribute and put name at runtime it throws me the following error

[[From [direct: get-token] ... because of headerName must be specified

Comment: Showing the relevant parts of your jboss-camel-context.xml (or all of it) might get you the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same effect with:

```
<setHeader headerName=...
```

> cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'headerName' is not allowed to
> appear in element 'setHeader'.

```
<setProperty propertyName=...
```

> cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'name' must appear on element
> 'setProperty'.

Note: I've found that the schema must be replaced by
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
--> http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.25.3.xsd

Is this really right?

Okay, since version 3.0 of camel-spring the schema has changed.
camel-spring.xsd is now directed to camel-spring-3.10.0.xsd. That was changed on 2021-05-21 12:21.

Comment: I don't understand this answer

Comment: if you want to continue using Camel 2.x, you need to change the schema to 2.25.3. Otherwise the scheme was changed with Camel 3.x. The correct syntax is now: setHeader name= or setProperty name=